# Get a File Which Contains Turkish Characters

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, special-characters

I am using Java with Rest api to get file from Sharepoint online. It is okay but if the file contains Turkish character i can't get it.

If the file name is "test.pfd" , i can open the file but the file name is "İtest.pdf" i can't. Do you know how to get the file?

```
    public void getTheFile(String sitePath, String path, String file) {
    try {

        String filePath = ProjectUtil.DESKTOP_PATH + file;
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        File f = new File(filePath);
        Boolean goAhead = false;

        if (f.exists()) {
            Object[] options = { "Yes", "No" };
            if (JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "There is the same file on your desktop. Are you sure?",
                    "Cancel", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                    options[1]) == 0) {
                goAhead = true;
            }
        } else {
            goAhead = true;
        }

        if (goAhead) {
            String siteURL = "https://" + SHAREPOINT_HOST + "/" + sitePath;

            String wsUrl = siteURL + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + path + "')/Files('" + file+ "')/$value";

            System.out.println(wsUrl);
            // Create HttpURLConnection
            URL url = new URL(wsUrl);
            System.out.println(url.toString());
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

            // Set Header
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json;  charset=utf-8");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + AUTH_TOKEN);



            // Read the response
            String httpResponseStr = "";
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                Files.copy(httpConn.getInputStream(), Paths.get(ProjectUtil.DESKTOP_PATH, file),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                //title="ModifiedBy"
                desktop.open(f);
            } else {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getErrorStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String strLine = "";
                while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    httpResponseStr = httpResponseStr + strLine;
                }

                System.out.println(httpResponseStr);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```